# How can I uncheck disabled radio buttons using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is some code that checks if a radio button is disabled. How do I reform this to make the radio unchecked if it is currently disabled? And yes I still want to remove the parent CSS class. Thanks.

```
$('input:disabled', true).parent().removeClass("style1");
```

Why won't this work?

```
$('input:disabled', true).attr('checked', false).parent().removeClass("style1");
```

Comment: Why *are* you passing `true` in for the context?

Comment: I looked at the usage on jquery.com and the example they showed had it just like that. Is it wrong syntax? Why does the 'checked' attribute get a true false?

Comment: @Nick: the relevant documentation can be found here: [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) - note that the second parameter is used to provide a staring point when matching the first parameter, so a boolean value has no meaning. Get rid of that, and you should be fine... Perhaps you were confused by the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) function, which takes a second parameter specifying the desired value for the attribute specified by the first parameter? I suspect Gumbo used to `removeAttr()` in his example to so as to avoid confusion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I reform this to make the radio
>   unchecked if it is currently disabled?

You could do:

```
$(':radio').each(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':disabled')) {
    $(this).attr('checked', false);
  }
});
```

**More Info:**

- [:radio Selector](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/)
- [:disabled Selector](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/)

Comment: I'm not using check boxes. I'm using radio buttons. I make a call to them using $('input') and they have a property named :checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:radio`](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) to only get radio buttons. And with the additional [`:disabled`](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) you will only get disabled radio buttons. So try this:

```
$(":radio:disabled").removeAttr("checked").parent().removeClass("style1")
```

Comment: I'm trying to use radio buttons. This doesn't seem to work: $('input:disabled', true).attr('checked', false).parent().removeClass("style1");

Comment: @Nick: Why do you use `true` as context? Please test the code as I wrote it.